# Efficient way to update/edit images in javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx

I have a simple tiled 2D game (battleships) I use one image for the game area (10x10) tiles by default and I need to update it if the player places the ship or attack and so on. The way I used is that I converted FX image to awt image, drew something and converted back to FX image because I've not found any way how to draw fx image. I can't use canvas because I need features of ImageView that doesn't support canvas and converting image to canvas and back to image would be probably as slow as my current solution. (by "slow" I mean application lag for a few seconds when I draw something).

my current code:

```
static Image updateBackground(Game game, ImageView image, TileEntry... entries) {
    BufferedImage img = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image.getImage(), null);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

    int imgWidth = (int) (image.getImage().getWidth() / game.getOptions().getLengthX());
    int imgHeight = (int) (image.getImage().getHeight() / game.getOptions().getLengthY());

    for(TileEntry entry : entries) {
        Vector2i pos = entry.getPos();
        Tile tile = entry.getTile();
        Bounds tileBounds = game.getController().getTileBounds(pos);

        Image source = null;

        switch (tile) {
            case SHIP:
                source = images.get(ResourceType.SHIP);
                break;
        }

        if (source != null) {

            int posX = (pos.getX() * imgWidth) - 10;
            int posY = pos.getY() * imgHeight;

            BufferedImage swingImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(source, null);
            swingImage.getScaledInstance(imgWidth, imgHeight, java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

            g.drawImage(swingImage, posX, posY, null);
        }
    }

    return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, null);
}
```

**EDIT:**

my code with canvas GraphicsContext

```
static Image updateBackground(Game game, ResizableCanvas canvas, TileEntry... entries) {
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    for(TileEntry entry : entries) {
        Vector2i pos = entry.getPos();
        Tile tile = entry.getTile();
        Bounds tileBounds = game.getController().getTileBounds(pos);

        switch (tile) {
            case SHIP:
                Image source = images.get(ResourceType.SHIP);
                gc.drawImage(source, tileBounds.getMinX(), tileBounds.getMinY());
                break;
            case HIT:
                gc.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
                gc.setLineWidth(10);
                gc.strokeLine(tileBounds.getMinX(), tileBounds.getMinY(), tileBounds.getMaxX(), tileBounds.getMaxY());
                gc.strokeLine(tileBounds.getMinX(), tileBounds.getMaxY(), tileBounds.getMaxX(), tileBounds.getMinY());
                break;
            case MARKED:
                gc.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
                gc.setLineWidth(10);
                gc.strokeLine(tileBounds.getMinX(), tileBounds.getMinY(), tileBounds.getMaxX(), tileBounds.getMaxY());
                gc.strokeLine(tileBounds.getMinX(), tileBounds.getMaxY(), tileBounds.getMaxX(), tileBounds.getMinY());
                break;
        }
    }

    return canvas.toImage();
}
```

Comment: Almost every approach should be better than converting to `BufferedImage` and back. Stacking multiple `ImageView`, using a `Canvas` (I don't see why you expect this to be problematic), ...

Comment: But into ImageView I can only put Image instance so should I use Canvas snapshot?

Comment: Why snapshot the canvas. The only drawing operation in the code I can see is drawing scaled images, which is possible in a `Canvas` as well without creating a snapshot. Alternatively it would also be possible by using a`ImageView` for each of the tiles...

Comment: I updated the code and added new one. I use ImageView to keep image size and size ratio, which isn't possible with Canvas. So I need to get Image instance as the result somehow.

Comment: Why is this impossible with `Canvas`? The calculation of the scale factor required for the drawn content to remain inside the canvas is quite simple, offset calculation in case you want to align the content isn't more difficult and `Canvas` can be resized...

Comment: Of course it isn't, but I didn't find the method that I could override or any kind of event, of course there is `ChangeListener` but I can't calculate layout there I think. Or if you could send me a topic where it's explained.

Comment: OK probably found a solution, I can bind it to my own ObservableValue thanks for your time :)

Comment: There is no reason why you need to switch to and from Swing in JavaFX. JavaFX's capabilities are beyond that of Swing's. It is very likely that a battleship game can be coded without drawing directly on a Canvas.